# Back button image for UIBarButtonItem has bizarre defect on Retina iPhone display

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, retina-display, appearance

I use the `appearance` method with UIBarButtonItem to customize the background images of my back button, but on the iPhone Retina display, I see a bizarre issue when using the image.

Here's an example of the non-Retina back button; you'll see that it looks fine:

[image]

However, the Retina version looks off. Appears as though the top few pixels of the image are reappearing down below:

[image]

Anyone else seen this before? How did you fix it?

Here's the code I'm using in my appDelegate to customize the UIBarButtonItem's back button:

```
UIImage *backButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 15, 5,5)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. My image was only 27 pixels tall; it should have been 30 pixels tall.

I didn't notice the issue on my rectangular UIBarButtonItem images, because rectangles can rescale without issue --- but with a pointed UIBarButtonItem image, you can't rescale without showing weird artifacts on the left-hand side from the pointed arrow.

tl;dr: Make your UIBarButtonItem images 30 and 60 pixels tall for your 1x and @2x sizes, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Follwoing code is from my project, I don't have problem. 
try to use below code snippet

```
UIImage* blueBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:blueBack forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```